# SerialPort: App causes Blue Screen on disconnecting device while it transfers data

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, bsod, uart

I working on a solution for device with Serial Port (with USB bridge).
Everything is ok except the thing it causes Blue Screen on disconnecting device durin data transfer.
And my app doesn't catch any exception about that. Is there any way to handle it? Ask users do not disconnect until data transferred completely is not a way.

I'm using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class to read data from device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is USB bridge problem. This will never happen with real serial port, with well written port driver. Serial port drivers in Windows, Linux and other OS are known as very stable and reliable. At the same time, buggy serial port emulations cause a lot of problems, from crashing a client application to blue screen.

The only thing you can do is to recommend to your customers to work with real serial port or stable port emulation (bridge), and avoid buggy serial port emulations like one you are working with.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your answer! You look competent in this question. But what can I do if I got a task to provide customer with a software for the device with Silab USB to UART bridge integrated. I've spent a few days trying to fix it and prevent system from being crashed. But nothing helped.. So asking users do not disconnect is the only really?

Comment: You cannot do anything because this is serial port emulation bug. Try to to find another stable product with the same functionality and recommend your customers to use it. There are lot of different serial port emulations in the market. The main rule is: if your program works with real serial port - it is OK. This is the problem that should be solved by port emulation developer.